# Inserting a node in a min-heap with a null value at the end

Tags: arrays, binary, binary-tree, heap, min-heap

I got a sorted min-heap array: `2,3,4,5,NULL`

I'd like to insert the value `1` in it, how would the first step be dealt with?

```
       2                     2
    /     \                /  \
   3       4   or this?   3    4
  / \      /             / \   
 5   NULL 1             5   1
```

Would be this the same if the node was empty instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A heap of integers does not have `NULL` values. I suppose the `NULL` is an indication of the capacity of the heap, meaning it can only have one more value before being full.

> Would be this the same if the node was empty instead?

As unusual as this representation is, the `NULL` cannot mean anything else than that the node *is* empty. If it is considered as *data*, then there is an inconsistency. The data type used for the values in a heap should be consistent, and comparable. So `NULL` is not an option for *data*.

When you insert a next value, the first empty slot should be used for it. And then it should be sifted to its correct position.

So from:

```
     2
    / \
   3   4
  / \     
 5   NULL
```

to

```
     2
    / \
   3   4
  / \
 5   1
```

to

```
     1
    / \
   2   4
  / \     
 5   3
```

BTW: a "sorted heap" is not a thing. True, a sorted list is also a heap, but the power of the heap is that it does not need to always be sorted. It only guarantees the heap property, i.e. that a parent node is never greater than either of its children.